# React Native Context dispatch delete current screen(item) causes render error

Tags: react-native

In my app, I have a list view of recipes and also a detail view of just one recipe.
I would like, in the detail view, to delete the recipe.

```
export default function RecipeDetails({ route, navigation }) {
  const { recipes, dispatch } = useContext(RecipeContext);

  const id = route.params.item.id;
  const currentRecipe = recipes.find((r) => r.id === id);
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          dispatch({ type: "remove", obj: currentRecipe });
          navigation.goBack();
        }}
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} size={20} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Image
        style={styles.img}
        source={images[currentRecipe.image]}
        resizeMode="cover"
      />
```

My goal is to dispatch the remove action and then go back to the list view. 
However, right now, after the dispatch of remove fires, I get an error saying "currentRecipe.image" is undefined.

My question is,  why doesn't the navigation direct back to the last screen(list view) so this undefined error won't occur ?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your component wants to re-render after the recipe is removed but before you navigate back -- it receives new props where the recipe is already gone and so `currentRecipe` is undefined and accessing `currentRecipe.image` throws an error.

What you can do is prevent accessing currentRecipe if it does not exist.

One way to do this is by returning null or a placeholder - this is not the most elegant solution:

```js
const currentRecipe = recipes.find((r) => r.id === id);

if (!currentRecipe) return null;
```

---

Alternatively, you can copy your recipe from context to local state for reading:

```js
const [currentRecipe] = useState(recipes.find((r) => r.id === id));
```

This will mean `currentRecipe` does not change after you have initially loaded it - not when you remove it, but also not when user edits it (if they have that option).

Comment: thank you :)
I think I should use the first suggested solution as I would like currentRecipe to be up to date with all the actions (remove and edit).